# Which is the best tense in the sentence

Tags: grammar

> I am doing the shopping today for a friend who is ill

Or

> I did the shopping today for a friend who is ill

Comment: In the first one, you might be at the shops, or will go there soon. In the second one, it's all over (the shopping, that is). So it depends on what you want to say.

Comment: It depends. Past simple is for things done (and finished) in the past.  The present continuous tense is for things you are doing now (or about now or in the very near future).  If the shopping is not yet finished use the present continuous, if it's all done, then use the past simple.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct depending on when you're intending to do the job.

"I am doing the shopping" means you're at the store *right now*, or you're just about to do it.  "I did the shopping" means you're already done with the task and talking about something earlier in the day.

Which is the best tense?  Well, that depends on what you meant to say.